# I am working on Sentimental analysis on twitter data got this error: Error in get_oauth_sig() : OAuth has not been registered for this session

Tags: r, twitter, data-science, sentiment-analysis

```
 >  oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth", access=                 "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_tocken" )
```

> download.file(url='http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem', destfile='cacert.pem')
>        trying URL 'http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem' Content type 'application/x-pem-file' length 236061 bytes (230 KB)
>        downloaded 230 KB

```
 > reqURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
 > accessURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
 > authURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
 > consumerKey <- 'key used'
 > consumerSecret <- 'key used'
 > accesstoken  <- 'key used'
 > accesssecret <- 'key used'
 > Cred = OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey, 
 +                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret, 
 +                         requestURL=reqURL, 
 +                         accessURL=accessURL, 
 +                         authURL=authURL)
 > Cred$handshake(cainfo= system.file('CurlSSL', 'cacert.pem', package = 'RCurl'))
 To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
 https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=0AflNwAAAAAA4AHwAAABYOpNKOk
 When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here: 9642678
 > save(Cred, file = 'twitter authentication.Rdata')
 > some_tweets = searchTwitter("trump", n=2000, lang = "en")
 **Error in get_oauth_sig() : OAuth has not been registered for this session**
```

how to solve this

Comment: You have to use valid key's and tokens by registering your app to Twitter, I believe you can do that [here](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new).

Comment: ya I have given valid key by creating app from apps.twitter.com

Comment: Was that token 'key used' or did you replace your own tokens for publishing the code here?

Comment: I have replaced with "key used" , sharing orignal key is not ethical I felt so

Comment: I got solution for this by changing the complete code. I used direct authorization technique, It has worked

Comment: Great that you were able to resolve your own issue! Feel free to add your solution as an answer to your own question, so others who encounter the same problem in the future know how to fix it.